# How to get State in FromRequest implementation with Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, rust-sqlx

I initialized a Mutex<[Pool<Postgres>](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.7/sqlx/struct.Pool.html)> instance and passed it to [manage](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.4.10/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.manage) method on `Rocket` instance in order to access the database on my controllers. What I usually do is:

```rust
// this is purely for example
#[get("/foo/bar")]
pub async fn controller<'a>(
    // ... others ...
    db_pool: &State<Mutex<PgPool>>,
    // ... others ...
) {
    // ... do other things ...
    let query_r = sqlx::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1")
        .bind(&id)
        .fetch_optional(&mut db_pool.inner().lock().await.acquire().await.unwrap()) // i reach `inner` of state, then `lock` the mutex, lastly `acquire` a pool connection
        .await; // type is Result<Option<PgRow>> i suppose, rust-analyzer is not very good at inferring it
    // ... do other things ...
}
```

This is cool and all but here's my problem: I wrote a struct as below...

```rust
pub struct User {
    id: usize,
    username: String,
    email: String,
}
```

...and I actually want to use it as request guard so that the client cannot hit the controllers if they haven't provided the correct credentials.

Official guide of Rocket [tells](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/requests/#request-guards) to implement [FromRequest](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html) trait so that it can be resolved as guard.

However, in order to initialize a `User` instance, I need to get a [PoolConnection](https://docs.rs/sqlx/0.5.7/sqlx/pool/struct.PoolConnection.html) inside this [FromRequest](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html) trait. I have dived into Rocket's API documentation and seems like [request parameter on FromRequest](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html#tymethod.from_request) has a method named [rocket](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/request/struct.Request.html#method.rocket) with returns a `Rocket<Orbit>` instance, and, with this, I can [access the state](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.state).

However, the problem is that [state](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/struct.Rocket.html#method.state) method returns `&Mutex<Pool<Postgres>>`, which is an immutable reference, so I cannot do any operations on database with this.

I have come this far and would like to ask if anyone knows a way to access `Mutex<Pool<Postgres>>` without a reference.

Thanks in advance.

## How Far I Have Come

Below is how I have implemented [FromRequest](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/request/trait.FromRequest.html).

```rust
pub struct User {
    id: usize,
    username: String,
    email: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum UserError {
    TokenError(TokenError),
    MissingToken,
    DatabasePoolError,
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for User {
    type Error = UserError;

    async fn from_request(request: &'r rocket::Request<'_>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let encrypted_token_o = request.headers().get_one("Authorization");

        match encrypted_token_o {
            Some(encrypted_token) => {
                let claims_r = Claims::try_from(encrypted_token.to_owned());

                match claims_r {
                    Ok(claims) => {
                        let db_pool_o = request.rocket().state::<Mutex<PgPool>>();

                        match db_pool_o {
                            Some(db_pool) => {
                                let id = 0; // a test id
                                let query_r = sqlx::query(
                                    "SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE id=$1",
                                )
                                .bind(&id)
                                .fetch_optional(
                                    // ERROR: no method named `inner` found for reference `&rocket::futures::lock::Mutex<Pool<Postgres>>` in the current scope
                                    &mut db_pool.inner().lock().await.acquire().await.unwrap(),
                                )
                                .await;
                                todo!()
                            }
                            None => request::Outcome::Failure((
                                http::Status::InternalServerError,
                                UserError::DatabasePoolError,
                            )),
                        }
                    }
                    Err(e) => request::Outcome::Failure((
                        http::Status::InternalServerError,
                        UserError::TokenError(e),
                    )),
                }
            }
            None => request::Outcome::Failure((http::Status::BadRequest, UserError::MissingToken)),
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Environment

- rustc 1.55.0
- rocket 0.5.0-rc.1 with features `default` and `json`
- sqlx 0.5.7 with features `runtime-tokio-native-tls`, `all-types`, `postgres` and `migrate`

Comment: Locking a mutex does not require it to be mutable, so you should be able to lock the mutex and access the database.

Comment: @Jbm | I've just tried removing `inner` and it does not raise compile time error. It seems you are right.